# How do I load large number drawable images into fragment ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I am developing an app for a book, which have 13 units, each unit contain many exercises and each exercise contains many scanned images(450 images in total).

Now I have a Main Menu Activity, and 2 fragments, `fragmentA` for showing the exercises in `ListView` and `fragmentB` for showing the scanned images of exercises.

My Main Menu Activity contain 13 buttons, each button for every unit, to load that unit's exercises.

I have created String `ArrayLists` of exercises for each unit separately, to load them into `fragmentA` when user tap on a specific unit.

1)  Now how do I load images in `fragmentB` in `ListView`?
`TypedArrays`, or should i create `integerArrays` in Main Menu class (1 `arraylist` for each exercise of all the units)?

When I set `OnItemClick` to `ListView` in `oncreateview` in `fragmentA` it assign the same action to all the 13 ArrayList's listview item i.e if I assign am image to exercise 1 of unit 1 it would assign that image to the exercise 1 of all units.

2) How do I implement `onItemClick` for all the exercises of all units separately?

Comment: 2) `OnItemClickListener` will give you the position in your list that has been clicked. Use that to do a lookup in your `ArrayList`  (`myList.get(position);`)

Comment: Fragment communication: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html  , also lookup the design "Master Detail view" it sounds like what you are describing. Maybe this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Fragments or http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial

Comment: I am using this but it gives me the same id for all the exercises     ` public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view;

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked # "
                        + position + "Which is List: " + view.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 0):

A few things you should consider before development:

1. Placing 450 images in your application can cause in huge size of application. Keep in mind that size limit for .apk file on Google Play is [100MB](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html)
2. To show images of such large scale on UI can take a lot of processing power and may result in [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html). You need to load images on UI asynchronously.

> how do i load images in fragmentB in ListView

You can make use of [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) in `FragmentB`

To show different content based on excercise, pass the position of clicked item from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB` and based on that position, set following item from `ArrayList` on UI.

Way to send parameters in fragment.

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("position", "0");
FragmentB fragmentB=new FragmentB();
fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
```

**Update**

You need to create model class to hold content e.g

**Unit.java**

```
public class Unit {
    public int unit;
    public ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;
}
```

Where `Exercise` is also a model class.

Comment: these images are really of small size like 20-30 KB per image so that's not a problem it will be 12mb in total, thats how am passing data from main activity to fragmentA  bundle.putStringArrayList(DATA, unit1);  bundle.putStringArrayList(DATA, unit2); and so on. now how do I get different ids for all the item of unit1 and for unit2 and unit3 so on?

Comment: you mean you are getting same position on clicking any item?

Comment: let's say I have Set a toast to exercise 1 if unit one, it will show the same toast to exercise 1 of unit2 and unit3 till 13, how can i get ids of all the listview items i.e different ids for all the exercises of 13 units so i could implement switch case for different actions on each different click?

Comment: I think the thing you are confusing is mapping of data on ArrayLists. How have you mapped units and exercises on ArrayLists?

Comment: I have created arraylist for each unit like this  ArrayList<String> unit1 = new ArrayList<String>(); now when i pass these lists to fragmentA like this  bundle.putStringArrayList(DATA, unit1); and receive it in fragment like this data = getArguments().getStringArrayList(MainMenu.DATA); then fragment  loads the DATA, and thats why onItemClick is assigning the same action for all item1 of each exercise? did u get what am saying? i think am confusing u too :)

Comment: and what about exercises? All you need is to create ArrayList of Objects like ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();. Object can be your class which contains unit, an ArrayList of excercises etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100283/discussion-between-anders-and-shahzeb).